# Problems with simple threadpool and TCP listener in C

Tags: c, pthreads, memset

I've implement a multi threaded TCP listener in c with a simple thread pool logic and I have two main problem after I tested with a `for((i=1;i<100000;i++)) do echo "Hi $i" |nc 127.0.0.1 2000;` in multiple terminals:

1. I would get 'pthread: Cannot allocate memory' after over 30000 packets even if I use pthread_exit() and pthread_join (with 5gb free memory and ps -hH shows only 4 to 5 threads) it will work only if I use pthread_detach(pthread_self()).
2. When I use pthread_detach(pthread_self()) I would get some extra character at my output, after I use memset(&buffer,0,sizeof buffer) on local buffer variable in handle_client function everything works fine but I guess there is a problem in my code which cause this.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define handle_err(msg)     \
    do                      \
    {                       \
        perror(msg);        \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
    } while (0)
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
#define MAX_ACCEPT_THREAD 200
uint empty_thread_sp = 1;
int empty_thread[MAX_ACCEPT_THREAD];
pthread_t *process_thread;
struct ip_args
{
    int port;
    int ipaddr;
};
struct client_thread
{
    unsigned int cfd;
    int thread_number;
};
int create_thread_pool()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ACCEPT_THREAD; i++)
    {
        empty_thread[i] = i;
    }
    process_thread =malloc(MAX_ACCEPT_THREAD * sizeof *process_thread);
}
int get_thread()
{

    if (empty_thread_sp < MAX_ACCEPT_THREAD)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        empty_thread_sp++;
        printf("ThreadNO_in_Get=%d\n", empty_thread[empty_thread_sp]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        return empty_thread[empty_thread_sp];
    }
    else
    {
        return get_thread();
    }
}
int release_thread(struct client_thread *ct)
{
    if (empty_thread_sp > 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        empty_thread[--empty_thread_sp] = ct->thread_number;
        printf("ThreadNO_in_R=%d\n", empty_thread[empty_thread_sp]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
void *handle_client(void *arg)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    int no;
    char buffer[1024];
    //TODO is this ok?
    memset(&buffer,0,sizeof buffer);
    struct client_thread *ct = arg;
    int n;
    n = read(ct->cfd, buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    write(ct->cfd, &buffer, strlen(buffer));
    close(ct->cfd);
    release_thread(ct);
    no = ct->thread_number;
    free(ct);
    //TODO the following lines do not work
    //pthread_exit(NULL);
    //pthread_join(process_thread[no],NULL);
    
}
void *start_listen(void *args)
{
    struct ip_args *listen_addr = args;
    unsigned int sfd;
    struct client_thread *ct; 
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sfd == -1)
        handle_err("socket");
    printf("%d\n", sfd);
    memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(listen_addr->ipaddr);
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(listen_addr->port);
    struct sockaddr_in peer_addr;
    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) < 0)
        handle_err("bind");
    if (listen(sfd, 10) == -1)
        handle_err("listen");

    while (1)
    {
        ct= malloc(sizeof *ct); 
        socklen_t addr_size = sizeof peer_addr;
        ct->cfd = accept(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&peer_addr, &addr_size);
        if (ct->cfd == 1)
            handle_err("accept");

        ct->thread_number = 0;
        ct->thread_number = get_thread();

        printf("Thread_number = %d\n", ct->thread_number);

        if (pthread_create(&process_thread[ct->thread_number], NULL, handle_client, (void *)ct) != 0)
            handle_err("pthread");
    }
}
int main()
{
    create_thread_pool();
    /* 1- socket 2-bind 3-listen 4-accept*/
    struct ip_args listen_addr1, listen_addr2, control_addr;
    listen_addr1.ipaddr = INADDR_ANY;
    listen_addr1.port = 2000;
    listen_addr2.ipaddr = INADDR_ANY;
    listen_addr2.port = 3000;
    control_addr.ipaddr = INADDR_LOOPBACK;
    control_addr.port = 57000;
    pthread_t listen_thread[3];
    pthread_create(&listen_thread[0], NULL, start_listen, (void *)&listen_addr1);
    pthread_create(&listen_thread[1], NULL, start_listen, (void *)&listen_addr2);
    //pthread_create(&listen_thread[2], NULL, start_listen, (void *)&control_addr);
    start_listen((void *)&control_addr);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edited:**
@terehpp Sample works fine but It only create 3 process thread, Based on a @Martin James and @terehpp suggestion I should change my design.
And about my second issue based on @terehpp hint I should use memset(&buffer,0,sizeof buffer) on a local non-static variable.

Comment: Can you check the return value of `pthread_detach()`?

Comment: Also, compile with ASan, and check for memory leaks. `pthread_exit` could be cleaning up for the thread, but there might be other leaks.

Comment: @TSG pthread_detach() value is 0.

Comment: gcc -pthread -lasan -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer listen.c and run ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out shows no problem.

Comment: If I remove pthread_detach(pthread_self()) and uncomment pthread_exit(NULL) in handle_client I will get ==1942826==ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to allocate 0xfe000 (1040384) bytes at address fd9f1de3000 (errno: 12)
==1942826==ReserveShadowMemoryRange failed while trying to map 0xfe000 bytes. Perhaps you're using ulimit -v
==1942826==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: allocator is out of memory trying to allocate 0x1d8 bytes
Aborted

Comment: That is not a simple tbread pool.  Simple thread pools work by posting work items to a producer-consumer queue upon which tbe pool threads wait.  Designs such as yours are difficult to get right, difficult to debug and inflexible:(

Comment: If you malloc the ct_temp before the accept(), you will not need to copy the struct.

Comment: You MUST completely and correctly handle the results returned from system calls like read(), write().

Comment: Since you create a new thread for every connection and then detach it, why bother with the array/pool thingy at all?

Comment: Thanks @MartinJames I removed ct_temp and malloc the ct before accept, Anyway I do not understand why using local variable instead of pointer causes a race condition.

Comment: @MartinJames because I wanted to limit thread number to MAX_ACCEPT_THREAD. what alternative I can use of pthread_create()?

Comment: @MartinJames TY I should read and learn about producer-consumer queue and try that too.

Comment: @Geo-7 an atomic integer.  Initialize to 0,  Check against limit after accept, if less, increment and carry on creating the client thread, else send a 'User limit exceeded' message to client and close the socket, (and free the ct_temp!).  Decrement the atomic just before a client<>server thread exits.

Comment: @MartinJames I should accept All connection. That is not an option for me.

Comment: @Geo-7 sorry, I misunderstood:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we talk only about pthread_join problem and don't touch design issues:

1. You should invoke pthread_join as close as you can to pthread_create (If you have joinable thread).
   I remove pthread_detach and invoke pthread_join after pthread_create in the start_listen function.
   Also you should free resources in the function where you allocated them.
   So I replace
   `free(ct);` from `handle_client` to `start_listen`

Something like this

```
     if (pthread_create(&process_thread[ct->thread_number], NULL, handle_client, (void *)ct) != 0) {                 
         handle_err("pthread");                                                                                      
     } else {                                                                                                        
         pthread_join(process_thread[ct->thread_number], NULL);
         // As long as we have threadpool we should reallocate resources for 
         // process_thread[ct->thread_number]
         // because after pthread_join it will be free automaticly
         //I just catch this error with coredump, so.....
         process_thread[ct->thread_number] = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
         // But I am not really sure this good solution, I think malloc at this place far far away from }good solution                                                                                    
     }                   }                                                                                            
     free(ct);
```

So, now it works without crash
for((i=1;i<100000;i++)) do echo "Hi $i" |nc 127.0.0.1 2000; in multiple terminals

2. I am not able to reproduce your second issue. Code with pthread_detach works well on my machine.

**Fixes after segmentation fault comment**

I change get_thread() and release_thread() methods, also some changes to the start_listener and handler method:

```
 int empty_thread_sp = MAX_ACCEPT_THREAD - 1;
 ...
 int get_thread()
 {
    while(1) {//My eyes bleeding, too....
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        if (empty_thread_sp >= 0) {
            int thread;
            printf("ThreadNO_in_Get=%d, index=%d\n",empty_thread[empty_thread_sp], empty_thread_sp);
            thread = empty_thread[empty_thread_sp];
            empty_thread_sp -= 1;

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            return thread;
         }

         pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
 }

 int release_thread(struct client_thread *ct)
 {
     pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
     empty_thread_sp += 1;
     empty_thread[empty_thread_sp] = ct->thread_number;
     printf("ThreadNO_in_R=%d, index=%d\n", empty_thread[empty_thread_sp], empty_thread_sp);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
     return 0;
 }

 void *handle_client(void *arg)
 {
     int no;
     char buffer[1024];
     memset(&buffer,0,sizeof buffer);
     struct client_thread *ct = arg;
     int n;
     n = read(ct->cfd, buffer, 1024);
     printf("%s", buffer);
     write(ct->cfd, &buffer, strlen(buffer));
     close(ct->cfd);
     return NULL;
  }
  
  void *start_listen(void *args)
  {
     struct ip_args *listen_addr = args;
     unsigned int sfd;
     struct client_thread *ct; 
     struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
     sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sfd == -1)
         handle_err("socket");
     printf("%d\n", sfd);
     memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));
     my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(listen_addr->ipaddr);
     my_addr.sin_port = htons(listen_addr->port);
     struct sockaddr_in peer_addr;
     if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) < 0)
         handle_err("bind");
     if (listen(sfd, 10) == -1)
         handle_err("listen");

     while (1)
     {
         ct= malloc(sizeof *ct); 
         socklen_t addr_size = sizeof peer_addr;
         ct->cfd = accept(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&peer_addr, &addr_size);
         if (ct->cfd == 1)
             handle_err("accept");

         ct->thread_number = get_thread();

         printf("Thread_number = %d\n", ct->thread_number);

         if (pthread_create(&process_thread[ct->thread_number], NULL, handle_client, (void *)ct) != 0){
             handle_err("pthread");
         } else {
             pthread_join(process_thread[ct->thread_number], NULL);
             release_thread(ct);
         }
         free(ct);
     }
  }
```

Comment: for second issue did you remove memset(&buffer,0,sizeof buffer); in handle_client()?

Comment: And this code does not work. At a compile time I'll get listen.c:126:49: warning: assignment to ‘pthread_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} from ‘void *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] and If I run it I'll get a segfault.

Comment: Yes you right it shoud be cast to pthread_t. I edit answer. After that warning gone.
Do you still have segfault after cast?

Comment: Yes I still have segfault after the cast, please consider that I'm sending packet on 3 different port 2000,3000,57000. as soon as I start sending packet on a second port I would get a segfault.

Comment: Hmm, I used only one port, I will check on different ports. Thank you.

Comment: Please, check update of answer. Last part works for 3 different port at the same time

Comment: Wow you have changed a lot of code, I'm away from laptop right now, I would try your code tomorrow but as I'm looking your code I think your code would use only 5 thread(3 for listener and 2 for process thread).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221724/discussion-between-terehpp-and-geo-7).